# What's the difference between "dawn" and "dawning"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, american-english

I googled and I found nothing useful. I know what *dawn* means but I can't figure out if *dawning* is the same thing or has a different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

They are often interchangeable, except in some special cases.

For instance, you can't say "Dawning broke over the valley settlement."

"Dawning" is, well, *verbish*. As the poet said.

Comment: agreed. You can say 'the dawn of a new age' *or* 'the dawning of a new age', but you can't say 'I got up just before dawning'.